# текст на button android автоматически преобразует в заглавные

Tags: android, android-layout

При создании кнопки (button) какой бы ни был передан ей текст, он показывается заглавными буквами. Код самый обыкновенный. Вот начало в xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="+"
        android:id="@+id/kn"
        android:onClick="onClick_kn">
    </Button>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="в архив"
        android:id="@+id/archive"
        android:onClick="to_archive" />
```

Так происходит со всеми кнопками в любом Окне, независимо от применяемого или нет стиля к кнопкам. В манифесте прописана тема:
android:theme="@style/AppTheme". Если ее убрать, ничего не меняется.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Для всех кнопок в проекте можно:

1. изменить стиль:

   ```
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
     <item name="buttonStyle">@style/NotCapsButton</item>
   </style>

   <style name="NotCapsButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
   </style>
   ```
2. использовать свой класс (для кнопок не из *AppCompat* использовать метод `setAllCaps()`):

   ```
   public class NotCapsButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
     super(context, attrs);
     setSupportAllCaps(false);
    }

    public Button(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
     super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
     setSupportAllCaps(false);
    }
   }
   ```

Для отдельной кнопки:

1. Указать параметр `textAllCaps` в xml-атрибутах:

   ```
   <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Button"
     android:textAllCaps="false" />
   ```
2. Программно выставить в коде:

   ```
   mButton.setSupportAllCaps(false); // для кнопок AppCompat
   mButton.setAllCaps(false); // для кнопок не AppCompat
   ```

   или

   ```
   mButton.setTransformationMethod(null);
   ```

Comment: Великолепно!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Так уж кнопки устроены. Просто используйте `TextView` вместо них.

Comment: Благодарю. Когда я смотрю другие примеры, там другое поведение текста: (https://habrahabr.ru/post/206012/)   Я хотел бы решить вопрос, используя кнопку, так как я применяю к ней свойство, позволяющее вставлять значок слева от текста: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_play_arrow_white_48dp"` и свой задний фон с эффектом расходящейся волны от перехода одного цвета в другой при нажатии. Возможно ли решить вопрос с использованием кнопки?

Comment: Всё это точно также делается и для `TextView`. И, пожалуй, проще его кастомизировать, чем кнопку.

Comment: И в разных версиях андроида кнопки (и многое другое) ведут себя по разному. Если не хотите от этого завистеть - используйте предложенный вариант.